# Why does my WP_Query not find one result?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I have a plugin I wrote which works perfectly for all functions except one.  The one which doesn't quite work is when I am performing a WP_Query within a REST API function which looks like this:

```
  $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'download',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => 100,
    'paged' => $request['id']
  );

  $posts = new WP_Query( $args );
```

It correctly returns every single `post_type` of type `download` except one which never get's included in the results.  If I use `get_post( 1256 )` then I get the following:

```
{
    "ID": 1256,
    "post_author": "1",
    "post_date": "2021-06-17 09:57:06",
    "post_date_gmt": "2021-06-17 08:57:06",
    "post_content": "An example: hello world",
    "post_title": "My Ticket",
    "post_excerpt": "",
    "post_status": "publish",
    "comment_status": "closed",
    "ping_status": "closed",
    "post_password": "",
    "post_name": "my-ticket",
    "to_ping": "",
    "pinged": "",
    "post_modified": "2021-06-17 10:28:08",
    "post_modified_gmt": "2021-06-17 09:28:08",
    "post_content_filtered": "",
    "post_parent": 0,
    "guid": "https://www.example.com/my-ticket",
    "menu_order": 0,
    "post_type": "download",
    "post_mime_type": "",
    "comment_count": "0",
    "filter": "raw"
}
```

This looks like my query is correct and this post should be returned, i.e. it's the correct download post_type and it is post_status of publish.

I can't see why else my query wouldn't work.  What have I missed or is there some other filter that would be stopping it being returned?

Comment: Your result is not going beyond 100 ?

Comment: It's a good question but I have 37 results excluding the missing one which is correct :-)

Comment: Are you sure there isn't any hook that might be excluding this particular post, somewhere in your codebase ?

Comment: A good way to debug this is to print raw `SQL` code from `$posts->request` and see check if there is anything that would be causing this issue.

Comment: You were correct.  AND wp_posts.ID NOT IN (1256) is in the SQL.  How can I  query my data correctly?  I can't turn off the plugins, I just want to control my own data..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have mentioned in the comment.

> You were correct. AND wp_posts.ID NOT IN (1256) is in the SQL. How can I query my data correctly? I can't turn off the plugins, I just want to control my own data.

As I don't have the plugin code, I would try to explain how you can bypass the exclusion of the post id.

Lets suppose this is the code that is excluding the post.

```
add_action('pre_get_posts','alter_query');

function alter_query($query) {
    $query-> set('post__not_in' ,array(33));
}
```

There can be other actions as well which would be triggering this exclusion.

If you are getting you code using the following function.

```php
function get_data() {
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'page',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => 100,
    );

    $posts = new WP_Query( $args );

    return $posts;
}

var_dump(get_data());
```

then you can get rid of the exclusion like this.

```php
function get_data() {
    // Remove the removal action
    remove_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'alter_query' );
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'page',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => 100,
    );

    $posts = new WP_Query( $args );

    // Add the removal action back.
    add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'alter_query' );

    return $posts;
}
```

This way your aren't acutally changing any code of your plugin, you are just switching it off when you want to run your code.

> ### This is just an example you would want to change it according to your own situation.

### Finding action code which is causing issue.

1. Install [Query Monitor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/) plugin and activate it.
2. Run your query on a particular page and visit the page with admin logged in. You will see query monitors tab on admin bar.
   [image]
3. Click on it to open and select Hooks and Actions.
   [image]
4. Make a search (ctrl + f) for "pre_get_posts" in the hooks column. This on the condition that `pre_get_posts` is only used to alter the query.
   [image]
5. Once you find the instance of you can check the name of the function. In this case : `alter_query()` and the location `wp-content/themes/storefront/functions.php:113`

> Once you have the function name you remove and add the action as shown above. `remove_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'alter_query' );`

Comment: Is there no way to do this just for one query without having to find and affect another plugin's filters?  Seems crazy I cannot just create a new "clean" instance of WP_Query, run my query and leave it at that.

Comment: @JohnnyJohnBoy, I am afraid there is no other way that i know of. I have updated my answer with `Finding action code which is causing issue.` section which tell you the steps on how to find the hook which is affecting your code.